# Charts in an oriented manifold with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, orientation

> Let $M$ be an oriented manifold (with boundary) with $dim (M)\ge 2$.
>   Show that there exists an atlas
>   $\{(U_{\alpha},\phi_\alpha)\}_{\alpha\in I}$ for the chosen
>   orientation such that $\forall\alpha\in I$ we have
>   $\phi_\alpha(U_\alpha)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or in
>   $\mathbb{R}^n_+$.

Let's choose an orientation, i.e. let's choose a maximal oriented atlas $\{(U_{\alpha},\phi_\alpha)\}_{\alpha\in I}$.

I know that
$$
\mathring{M}:=\{p\in M:\exists (U,\phi), p\in U, \phi(U)\,\,\text{open}\,\, \text{in}\,\, \mathbb{R}^n \}\\
\partial M=\{p\in M:\forall (U,\phi),p\in U,\phi(p)\in\partial\mathbb{R}^n_{\pm}\}
$$
I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Why don't you simply take what you know, collect one such $(U,\phi)$ for each $p \in M$ into one set, and call that the atlas?

Comment: What do you mean? I can't understand...